# PostgreSQL Index physical layout

Tags: postgresql, b-tree-index

I am trying to understand how PostgreSQL physical index layout is. What I came to know is indexes are stores as part of set of pages with a B tree data structure. I am trying to understand how vacuumming impacts indexes. Does it help to contain its size?

Answer (score 4):

B-tree indexes are decade-old technology, so a web search will turn up plenty of good detailed descriptions. In a nutshell:

A B-tree is a *balanced tree* of index pages (8KB in PostgreSQL), that is, every branch of the tree has the same *depth*.
The tree is usually drawn upside down, the starting (top) node is the *root node*, and the pages at the bottom are called *leaf nodes*.
Each *level* of the tree partitions the search space; the deeper the level, the finer the partitioning, until the individual index entries are reached in the leaf nodes.
Each entry in an index page points to a table entry (in the leaf nodes) or to another index page at the next level.

This is a sketch of an index with depth three, but mind the following:

- some nodes are omitted, in reality *all* leaf nodes are on level 3
- in reality here are not three entries (*keys*) in one node, but around 100

```
                                     ┌───────────┐
                level 1 (root node)  │ 20 75 100 │
                                     └───────────┘
                                   ╱    ╱   │     ╲
                                  ╱    ╱    │      ╲
                                 ╱    ╱     │       ╲
                    ┌───────────┐┌─────┐┌──────────┐┌─────┐
           level 2  │ 5  10  15 ││ ... ││ 80 87 95 ││ ... │
                    └───────────┘└─────┘└──────────┘└─────┘
                                       ╱   ╱   │    ╲
                                      ╱   ╱    │     ╲
                                     ╱   ╱     │      ╲
                             ┌─────┐┌─────┐┌──────────┐┌─────┐
        level 3 (leaf nodes) │ ... ││ ... ││ 89 91 92 ││ ... │
                             └─────┘└─────┘└──────────┘└─────┘
```

Some notes:

- The pointers to the next level are actually in the gaps between the entries, searching in an index is like “drilling down” to the correct leaf page.
- Each node ia also linked with its siblings to facilitate insertion and deletion of nodes.
- When a node is full, it is split in two new nodes. This splitting can recurse up and even reach the root node. When the root node is split, the depth of the index increases by 1.
- In real life, the depth of a B-tree index can hardly exceed 5.
- When an index entry is deleted, an empty space remains. There are techniques to consolidate that by joining pages, but this is tricky, and PostgreSQL doesn't do that.

Now to your question:

When a table (*heap*) entry is removed by `VACUUM` because it is not visible for any active snapshot, the corresponding entry in the index is removed as well. This results in empty space in the index, which can be reused by future index entries.

Empty index pages can be deleted, but the depth of the index will never be reduced. So mass deletion *can* (after `VACUUM` has done its job) reduce the index size, but will more likely result in a *bloated index* with pages that contain only few keys and lots of empty space.

A certain amount of index bloat (up to more than 50%) is normal, but if unusual usage patterns like mass updates and deletes cause bad index bloat, you'll have to rewrite the index with `REINDEX`, thereby getting rid of bloat. Unfortunately this operation locks the index, so that all concurrent access is blocked until it is done.